# How to setup carndano node-socket?

Tags: cardano-node

I am executing the following query and then I am getting the following error.

The query I am executing.

```
cardano-cli query utxo --address $(cat payment.addr) --testnet-magic 1097911063
```

And the error I am getting.

```
Command failed: query utxo  Error: Error while looking up environment variable: CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH  Error: "CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH"
```

How do i debug this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Ensure that `cardano-node` is running.
2. open a new terminal window, and enter `nano ~/.bashrc`
3. Scroll to the bottom of the file and add the following line:

`EXPORT CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH=/home/user/cardnao/db/socket` (or whatever the path is to the socket in your `db` folder)

4. Save the file and exit, then in the same terminal window, type: `source ~/.bashrc` and hit enter.
5. Now things should work. To check if the socket path is recognized, run:

`cardano-cli query tip --testnet-magic 1097911063`, and you should receive a sync status update. Comment if you're still getting an error.

Comment: How do i know the path of socket?

Comment: when you run `cardano-node`, one of the mandatory flags is to specify a db folder. When you do that, a socket file is automatically created in that folder. CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH in your `~/.bashrc` folder must then be pointed to that socket (following the instructions above)

Comment: `EXPORT CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH=/home/user/cardnao/db/socket` How do i know `/home/user/cardnao/db/socket` With what I have to replace this with?